# GEE: how to get ImageCollection property name

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm using the ee.Filter.eq function like this:

```
collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA')\
        .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2018-01-01')\
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11, 2, 'month'))\
        .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(25.8544, -18.08874))

print(collection.size().getInfo())
filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.eq('CLOUD_COVER', 0))
print(filtered.size().getInfo())
```

I get collection size = 41 and filtered size = 2, which means I filter the ImageCollection by property 'CLOUD_COVER'.
But when I use the 'propertyNames' function to look up the property:

```
print(collection.propertyNames().getInfo())
```

the output is:

```
['system:version', 'system:id']
```

There seems no 'CLOUD_COVER'.
I want to get a property list containing 'CLOUD_COVER', then I can know which property I can use to filter the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that both, image collections and images have their own properties. Thus, the line `collection.propertyNames()` returns the **image collection** properties. However, to filter an image collection, you usually want to use the **image** properties to only return the images that match certain condition. Therefore, to show the properties of the images contained in an image collection you can use:

```
print(collection.first().propertyNames())
```

In this list you will see the `'CLOUD_COVER'` property and additional ones, which you can use to construct custom filters. Finally, if you wish to consult the values of a particular property of the images contained in an image collection, you should use:

```
print(collection.aggregate_arrat('CLOUD_COVER'))
```